# Can OpenLayers 3 run without browser or is it designed to be used only in browser?

Tags: openlayers, open-source-gis, node-js, browser

I need to run OpenLayers app which will render some map into canvas and then I need url of that canvas ( Canvas.toDataUrl() ), I would use NodeJS and Node Canvas to get it done. I wonder can OpenLayers run without browser?

Comment: What stops you from trying?

Comment: Why do you need to use Openlayers without browser?